# Having trouble with authentication to access API

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to retrieve information from an API. The API requires authentication in order to access it. I have the tried the following, but it says that the Authentication has failed. I already confirmed that the credentials are correct, so that is not the problem. Any suggestions?

```
$pro = '0000000000';
            $userName = 'userName';
            $password = 'password';
            $userPass = $userName.':'.$password;


            $host = 'https://wardtlctools.com/wardtrucking/webservices/imaging'; 

            $post = array(

                'User' => array(

                    'UserName' => $userName,
                    'Password' => $password

                    ),

                'Reference' => array(

                    'RefNo' => $pro,
                    'RefType' => 'WARDPRO',
                    'DelMethod' => 'Link',
                    'Documents' => array(

                        'DocType' => 'BL',
                        'DocType' => 'DR'

                        )

                    )

                );

            $ch = curl_init($host);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userPass);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $return = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            print_r($return);
```

This is the documentation from the provider's website.

[image]

Comment: your site must have HTTPS to access this api.

Comment: @Smartpal my site does have https

Comment: API may be down, I've ping site!

Comment: @Smartpal Yeah, just noticed the same thing. Thank you!

Comment: @Smartpal do you see anything I might be doing wrong in my code though?

Comment: Your code looks like minimal working code, try when API site get `UP`